# I'm getting an error unhandledRejection on my terminal after making a server request on postman which also returned an error 401

Tags: javascript, mongodb, server, next.js

```
unhandledRejection: MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/home/codexpath/Desktop/code_demo/restaurant_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:207:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/codexpath/Desktop/code_demo/restaurant_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:60:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (/home/codexpath/Desktop/code_demo/restaurant_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:132:20)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/codexpath/Desktop/code_demo/restaurant_app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at 
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'HandshakeError' }
}
```

Comment: Good for you, but what is the question?

Comment: i'm meant to get the success message on postman coz i have no error in my code but it keeps returning Not authenticated ! and my mongodb is not showing me the database i linked to it

Comment: We can't help you right now, we need more details about your authentication, i guess your credentials are wrong, try to dump the credentials, to see if they actually exist and are correct